# change name of calendar export from "liferay.ics"

Tags: properties, calendar, liferay

Someone know how to change the filename of the liferay calendar event before export?
The default one is "liferay.ics".

Thanks 
Sabrina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the name by writting an hook.

Override the export_import.jspf file located at %liferay_folder%\%your_server%\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\calendar

```
<aui:fieldset label="export">
        <aui:input cssClass="lfr-input-text-container" label="" name="exportFileName" type="text" value="liferay.ics" />
    </aui:fieldset>
```

Changing the value attribute should do the trick.

---

Owk after looking a bit closer to the calendar portlet it appears that my above solution is only visible on the export/import tab and not when you export an event from the summary tab.

The endpoint who is responsible for creating the file: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/liferay/portal/portal-impl/6.1.0/portal-impl-6.1.0-sources.jar!/com/liferay/portlet/calendar/action/ExportEventsAction.java?format=ok

It appears that when no portlet parameter with the name exportFileName is set the action will automaticly name it liferay.ics:

### Short And Easy fix:

Add (in event_action.jsp):

```
<portlet:param name="exportFileName" value="<%= event.getTitle() %>" />
```

to :

```
<c:if test="<%= CalEventPermission.contains(permissionChecker, event, ActionKeys.VIEW) %>">
        <portlet:actionURL windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>" var="exportURL">
            <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/calendar/export_events" />
            <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
            <portlet:param name="eventId" value="<%= String.valueOf(event.getEventId()) %>" />
        </portlet:actionURL>

        <liferay-ui:icon
            image="export"
            url='<%= exportURL %>'
        />
    </c:if>
```

---

### Write an wrapper arround the ExportEventsAction. (For more Advance senarios)

Use this method when more advance operations are required in the future.

- http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/7132115
- https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/hooks/sample-struts-action-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/samplestrutsaction/hook/action/SampleStrutsPortletAction.java

Wrapper basic concepts:

In your hook xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_1_0.dtd">

<hook>

    <custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/jsps/</custom-jsp-dir>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/calendar/export_events</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>aiao.liferay.strutsactions.ExportEventActionWrapper</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>
</hook>
```

Your wrapper looks like this:

```
public class ExportEventActionWrapper extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {

    @Override
    public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        _logger.info("Call To Wrapper");

        //do your magic here...

        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }

    private Log _logger = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(ExportEventActionWrapper.class);

}
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it in my hook, I checked if is modified in tomcat file, and I reboot liferay, but the new name still not appear during ics download.. do you know if I'm missing something? Thanks Sabrina